# Text To Speech API Not Working on iOS

Tags: ios, api, ipad, safari, speech

For the following code, it does not work on iOS Safari(iPad Air 2). It works  everywhere else (Safari on Mac, Chrome on windows)

When I tried to debug the script below on the iPad's Safari (connected to Mac), it does not give any error. It is just silent. No speech.

Please not that this is the simple script, I created many others, such as setting up the voice etc.Nothing works..There is also a separate problem getting the voices, but I want to see if it works with the default voice first.

P.S. If I do XCode programming, using swift to develop native code on iPad (not in Safari), speech works on the iPad. But my goal is to create a web page using the Speech API

Thanks.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function Speak() {
            speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello, this is my voice on a webpage"));

            var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            speech.text = "Hello";
            speech.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
            speech.rate = 1; // 0.1 to 9
            speech.pitch = 1; // 0 to 2, 1=normal
            speech.lang = "en-US";
            speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
        }
    </script>
    <a  onclick="Speak()">ClickMe</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. It works with Chrome, Firefox and Opera Apps though.

Answer (score 3):

Check your volume, mute switch and make sure you don't have bluetooth headphones set up. It must also be within a click event (which you are doing). Try a normal video to make sure you get sound.

What made it work for me?

- I went downstairs
- I watched a video in Safari
- I tried again and it worked
- I then tried again and it worked
- I tried again and it didn't work
- I played a video again
- It still didn't work
- I force quit EVERYTHING
- It then worked
- And then it didn't
- Then I realized I hadn't closed browser tabs
- Then it worked

I think there's a bug (iOS11)

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that I went upstairs again at some point. Hope that helps.

Comment: Going upstairs worked for me! how could you miss such valuable information?